# java OutOfMemoryError in hudson

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

Im getting the following error while running pmd, findbugs in hudson.

```
FATAL: Java heap space  
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space  
    at java.util.HashMap.(Unknown Source)  
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.AnnotationContainer.initialize(AnnotationContainer.java:163)  
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.AnnotationContainer.(AnnotationContainer.java:119)  
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.WorkspaceFile.(WorkspaceFile.java:25)  
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.AnnotationContainer.addFile(AnnotationContainer.java:303)  
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.AnnotationContainer.updateMappings(AnnotationContainer.java:212)  
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.AnnotationContainer.addAnnotation(AnnotationContainer.java:317)  
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.AnnotationContainer.addAnnotations(AnnotationContainer.java:327)  
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.BuildResult.initialize(BuildResult.java:266)  
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.BuildResult.(BuildResult.java:206)  
    at hudson.plugins.findbugs.FindBugsResult.(FindBugsResult.java:40)  
    at hudson.plugins.findbugs.FindBugsPublisher.perform(FindBugsPublisher.java:132)  
    at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwarePublisher.perform(HealthAwarePublisher.java:280)  
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$2.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:27)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:603)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:582)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:560)  
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:156)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:529)  
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1349)  
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)  
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)  
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:139)
```

I have specified jvmargs for pmd, findbugs and ant_opts is set to 1024M.

Comment: Are you running Hudson from the command-line or through a servlet container such as Apache Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in windows you must edit the hudson.xml file to include the java argument
-Xmx1024m, however if you're on a *nix environment you must run the command

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
```

Or a more reasonable size for memory.