# OutOfMemoryError in hudson

Tags: hudson, hudson-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java OutOfMemoryError in hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881787/java-outofmemoryerror-in-hudson)

I'm getting following error in hudson ver 1.395

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 16 minutes 44 seconds
FATAL: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.jvnet.winp.Native.getCmdLineAndEnvVars(Native Method)
    at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.parseCmdLineAndEnvVars(WinProcess.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.getEnvironmentVariables(WinProcess.java:109)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Windows$1.getEnvironmentVariables(ProcessTree.java:419)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$OSProcess.hasMatchingEnvVars(ProcessTree.java:259)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Windows.killAll(ProcessTree.java:441)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:657)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:441)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1362)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)

Answer (score 1):

See documentation: [Hudson - OutOfMemoryError](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/I%27m+getting+OutOfMemoryError)

You can also try to increase heap like that: java -jar hudson.war -Xms64m -Xmx256m (default is: -Xms32m -Xmx128m)